# How to execute a stored procedure within C# program

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to execute this stored procedure from a C# program.

I have written the following stored procedure in a SqlServer query window and saved it as 
stored1:

```
use master 
go
create procedure dbo.test as

DECLARE @command as varchar(1000), @i int
SET @i = 0
WHILE @i < 5
BEGIN
Print 'I VALUE ' +CONVERT(varchar(20),@i)
EXEC(@command)
SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

**EDITED:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace AutomationApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public void RunStoredProc()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            SqlDataReader rdr  = null;

            Console.WriteLine("\nTop 10 Most Expensive Products:\n");

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=master;Integrated Security=SSPI");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.test", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                /*while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Product: {0,-25} Price: ${1,6:####.00}",
                        rdr["TenMostExpensiveProducts"],
                        rdr["UnitPrice"]);
                }*/
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
                if (rdr != null)
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Program p= new Program();
            p.RunStoredProc();      
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

This displays the exception `Cannot find the stored procedure dbo.test`. Do I need to provide the path? If yes, in which location should the stored procedures be stored?

Comment: You are better off to use a database other than master even for testing. This is a system database and you will cause problems eventually. In SQL 2012 it wont let me create a table there. It will conversely allow me to create a sproc. :/

Comment: Answers notwithstanding: have you checked if your sp was actually created with the name you gave(dbo.test)? I don't know what would happen if a non-dbo user tries to create dbo.test... would it be created as non-dbo.test?

Comment: @obayhan This question was asked 2 years before the one you claim it is a possible duplicate of. Please, in future, mark the most recent question as the duplicate.

Answer (score 391):

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", conn) { 
                           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You can even get rid of the `conn.Close`, is implied by the `Dispose`

Comment: That's true for this case. I like to have matching `Open` and `Close` calls. If you say, refactor the connection object out as a field in the future and remove the using statement, you might accidentally forget to add `Close` and end up with an open connection.

Comment: How would you do this if the stored proc needed parameters? just add the parameters to the command object with the same names and types?

Comment: @Dani Yes. Just add the parameters to the `Parameters` collection of the `SqlCommand` object.

Answer (score 294):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI")) {
    conn.Open();

    // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
    SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("CustOrderHist", conn);

    // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custId));

    // execute the command
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        // iterate through results, printing each to console
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Product: {0,-35} Total: {1,2}",rdr["ProductName"],rdr["Total"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some interesting links you could read:

- http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dclark/InsOutsinCS11302005072332AM/InsOutsinCS.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simplecodeasp.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171921(VS.80).aspx

Comment: You should really use "using" keyword. Push that open/close responsibility to the framework.

Comment: Definition of SqlCommand: `public sealed class SqlCommand : System.Data.Common.DbCommand, ICloneable, IDisposable`.  Put it into `using` statement will help cleaning up.

Answer (score 40):

Calling stored procedure in C#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName",con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value",txtValue.Text);

con.Open();
int rowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 25):

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String")) {
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
  Int32 rowsAffected;

  cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

  sqlConnection1.Open();

  rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}}
```

Comment: I am worried about how the cmd.CommandText = "Stored1" interpretes my stored procedure.I dont know.

Comment: The "CommandText" must be set to the NAME of the stored procedure, which is then executed from C# as if you had executed "exec StoredProcedureName" in SSMS - or what are you worried about?

Comment: How can i give the storedprocedure name for the above stored procedure
can u plz tell me??

Comment: so, first, you would have to create the stored procedure, in the case of the code you have, you would need to add: "create procedure dbo.NameOfYourStoredProcedureHere as" at the beginning

Comment: @Cute: if you have this as a stored procedure, you **MUST** have a name! The name used in the "CREATE PROCEDURE (procedurename)" call. If you do not have that, then you do not have a stored procedure (but just a batch of T-SQL statements) and then you cannot use the "CommandType = StoredProcedure", obviusly

Comment: Your stored procedure is not returning anything - use  .ExecuteNonQuery()   (as the answer here says)  instead of .ExecuteReader()

Answer (score 19):

This is code for executing stored procedures with and with out parameters via reflection.
Do note that the objects property names need to match the parameters of the stored procedure.

```
private static string ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
    private SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

    public void ExecuteStoredProcedure(string procedureName)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnObj = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConnObj);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlConnObj.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnObj.Close();
    }

    public void ExecuteStoredProcedure(string procedureName, object model)
    {
        var parameters = GenerateSQLParameters(model);
        SqlConnection sqlConnObj = new SqlConnection(ConnString);

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConnObj);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        sqlConnObj.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnObj.Close();
    }

    private List<SqlParameter> GenerateSQLParameters(object model)
    {
        var paramList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        Type modelType = model.GetType();
        var properties = modelType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.GetValue(model) == null)
            {
                paramList.Add(new SqlParameter(property.Name, DBNull.Value));
            }
            else
            {
                paramList.Add(new SqlParameter(property.Name, property.GetValue(model)));
            }
        }
        return paramList;

    }
```

Answer (score 16):

```
SqlConnection conn = null;
SqlDataReader rdr  = null;
conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
conn.Open();

// 1.  create a command object identifying
//     the stored procedure
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("CustOrderHist", conn);

// 2. set the command object so it knows
//    to execute a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// 3. add parameter to command, which
//    will be passed to the stored procedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custId));

// execute the command
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// iterate through results, printing each to console
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Product: {0,-35} Total: {1,2}", rdr["ProductName"], rdr["Total"]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**By using Ado.net**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace PBDataAccess
{
    public class AddContact
    {   
        // for preparing connection to sql server database   

        private SqlConnection conn; 

        // for preparing sql statement or stored procedure that 
        // we want to execute on database server

        private SqlCommand cmd; 

        // used for storing the result in datatable, basically 
        // dataset is collection of datatable

        private DataSet ds; 

        // datatable just for storing single table

        private DataTable dt; 

        // data adapter we use it to manage the flow of data
        // from sql server to dataset and after fill the data 
        // inside dataset using fill() method   

        private SqlDataAdapter da; 


        // created a method, which will return the dataset

        public DataSet GetAllContactType() 
        {



    // retrieving the connection string from web.config, which will 
    // tell where our database is located and on which database we want
    // to perform opearation, in this case we are working on stored 
    // procedure so you might have created it somewhere in your database. 
    // connection string will include the name of the datasource, your 
    // database name, user name and password.

        using (conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["conn"]
        .ConnectionString)) 

                {
                    // Addcontact is the name of the stored procedure
                    using (cmd = new SqlCommand("Addcontact", conn)) 

                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // here we are passing the parameters that 
                    // Addcontact stored procedure expect.
                     cmd.Parameters.Add("@CommandType",
                     SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "GetAllContactType"; 

                        // here created the instance of SqlDataAdapter
                        // class and passed cmd object in it
                        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 

                        // created the dataset object
                        ds = new DataSet(); 

                        // fill the dataset and your result will be
                        stored in dataset
                        da.Fill(ds); 
                    }                    
            }  
            return ds;
        }
}

****** Stored Procedure ******

CREATE PROCEDURE Addcontact
@CommandType VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@CommandType = 'GetAllContactType')
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Contacts
  END
END
```

Comment: Your comment lines are broken, also if you can give stored procedure in your comment that would good for us.

Comment: have added the stored procedure in code, check it out.

Answer (score 4):

this is an example of a stored procedure that returns a value and it's execution in c#

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPerson]   
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here  
@FirstName nvarchar(50),@LastName nvarchar(50),  
@PersonID int output  
AS  
BEGIN  
    insert [dbo].[Person](LastName,FirstName) Values(@LastName,@FirstName)  

    set @PersonID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
END  
Go  


--------------
 // Using stored procedure in adapter to insert new rows and update the identity value.  
   static void InsertPersonInAdapter(String connectionString, String firstName, String lastName) {  
      String commandText = "dbo.InsertPerson";  
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {  
         SqlDataAdapter mySchool = new SqlDataAdapter("Select PersonID,FirstName,LastName from [dbo].[Person]", conn);  

         mySchool.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);  
         mySchool.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

         mySchool.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(  
             new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "FirstName"));  
         mySchool.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(  
             new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "LastName"));  

         SqlParameter personId = mySchool.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PersonID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "PersonID"));  
         personId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  

         DataTable persons = new DataTable();  
         mySchool.Fill(persons);  

         DataRow newPerson = persons.NewRow();  
         newPerson["FirstName"] = firstName;  
         newPerson["LastName"] = lastName;  
         persons.Rows.Add(newPerson);  

         mySchool.Update(persons);  
         Console.WriteLine("Show all persons:");  
         ShowDataTable(persons, 14);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Dapper. so i added this i hope anyone help.

```
public void Insert(ProductName obj)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection.GetConnectionString());
            connection.Open();
            connection.Execute("ProductName_sp", new
            { @Name = obj.Name, @Code = obj.Code, @CategoryId = obj.CategoryId, @CompanyId = obj.CompanyId, @ReorderLebel = obj.ReorderLebel, @logo = obj.logo,@Status=obj.Status, @ProductPrice = obj.ProductPrice,
                @SellingPrice = obj.SellingPrice, @VatPercent = obj.VatPercent, @Description=obj.Description, @ColourId = obj.ColourId, @SizeId = obj.SizeId,
                @BrandId = obj.BrandId, @DisCountPercent = obj.DisCountPercent, @CreateById =obj.CreateById, @StatementType = "Create" }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: It is best to use `using` before the connection declaration, or put the Close in a `finally` block. Otherwise, if an exception occurs, the connection will never be closed.

Answer (score 2):

No [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) answer here. So I added one

```
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

using (var cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local);DataBase=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
    cn.Execute("dbo.test", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check out Crane (I'm the author)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Crane/

```
SqlServerAccess sqlAccess = new SqlServerAccess("your connection string");
var result = sqlAccess.Command().ExecuteNonQuery("StoredProcedureName");
```

Also has a bunch of other features you might like.

Comment: How do you return multiple datasets with Crane ? My stored proc returns 3 datasets, and I am only interested in the second dataset. But Crane only returns me the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You mean that your code is DDL?
If so, MSSQL has no difference. Above examples well shows how to invoke this. Just ensure

```
CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Most Simple and straight forward..

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName",con); // Just like you declared it
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // an attribute related to the object
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value",txtValue.Text); // Parameter name and text source 

con.Open();
int rowAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I made, in my case I wanted to show procedure's result in dataGridView:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureNameHere", connection) {
            // Set command type and add Parameters
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Parameters = { new SqlParameter("@parameterName",parameterValue) }
        }) 
        {
            // Execute command in Adapter and store to dataset
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            var dataset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            // Display results in DatagridView
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
        }
```