# SQL Query depending on a Winform control. C#, VS2010

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I new to C#, and trying to make a winform app, i am having problem to search a Database depending upon the text entered in a textbox.

I have added the gridview, when adding a new query, what should be the WHERE clause like to be able to use data from Winform controls?

Also do i need to change the fill table call ?

And is there any Good books that may cover a good amount of similar topic,i.e,working with databases in c# winforms?

Thank you all, in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into making a stored procedure for your query and then you supply the value from your textbox.Text field into your stored procedure.

This other question might help you with the C# syntax: 
[How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-from-c-program)

And assuming you're trying out SQL Server Express, this should help you setup the query as a stored procedure: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx

Otherwise if you're going for basic SQL in the winForm, you likely want to run the query based on the user pressing a button rather than the "TextChanged" event on the TextBox:

```
String queryStr = "SELECT * "+
    "FROM my_table "+
    String.Format("WHERE my_value = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: i am a newbie(wrt to databases) so pls bear with it, can you pls tell me how should i execute this queryStr, and then populate the gridView with the result?? (i am using SQl Server)
Also pls suggest some book where i may find how to work with DB in c#

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth looking into linqto sql or linq to entities. Then you could do it somewhat like

```
  var q = from s in recs.Record
          where s == txtBox.Text 
          select s;
```

There are plenty of online resources for linq and it sort of creates a data access layer for you.