# Use stored procedure in EF(MVC4)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a storedprocedure "SelectKP" (Datetime bt,Datetime et), please help to create a class and a repository for this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:
[How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-program)

There is not a function generated manually, but it executes stored procedure

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I was a little mistake in the question, i need add function manual

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand meaning of the word manual in this context

Comment: @He11b0rn, so you mean a user-defined function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example.

```
using (var db = new ModelEntities())
{
  var query = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<ModelClass>("StoreProcedureName '" + UserId +"'");
}
```