# Insert into C# with SQLCommand

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sqlcommand

What's the best way to INSERT data into a database?

This is what I have but it's wrong..

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO klant(klant_id,naam,voornaam) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", klantId));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param2", klantNaam));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param3", klantVoornaam));
```

The function add data into the listBox

http://www.pictourl.com/viewer/37e4edcf *`(link is dead)`*

but not into the database..

http://www.pictourl.com/viewer/4d5721fc *`(link is dead)`*

The full function:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    conn2 = new SqlConnection();
    conn2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connSpionshopString"].ConnectionString;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    string sqlCmd = "SELECT naam,voornaam,klant_id FROM klant;";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, conn2);

    conn2.Open();

    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0) + " " + reader.GetString(1) + "  (" + reader.GetInt16(2) + ")");
        }  
    }
    conn2.Close();
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int klantId = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    string klantNaam = textBox2.Text;
    string klantVoornaam = textBox3.Text;

    conn2.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn2;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO klant(klant_id, naam, voornaam)   VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", klantId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", klantNaam);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", klantVoornaam);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    conn2.Close();
}
```

Comment: "It's wrong" is about as vague as you can be about what's happening. Please explain what you're observing. Note that you do need to actually *execute* the command...

Comment: Can you give more details? What do you mean it's wrong?

Comment: Are you opening and closing a connection and executing the query?

Comment: Don't use direct INSERT/UPDATE/EDIT commands in code, it is not a good practice. Try stored procedures.

Comment: If that's your code and you're pressing `button4` and then `button2`, the values *are* being inserted into your database. There's no other way it would get loaded into the listbox! I'll bet whatever you're using to look at the database is looking at a snapshot-read transaction and so it *appears* nothing changed.

Comment: @lc yes, its a duplicate version.. 

That's my code, and no the values are not being insterted into my databse :s

Comment: @KevinDW If you are so sure as to assert it is not being added into the database, then how are you populating the listbox? I see your code here hits the database for the listbox - if it comes out it must have been put in...?!?

Comment: This is duplicate of a question that has already been closed.  And it still does not even have a try catch block that was the first comment in the closed question.

Comment: I have a try catch block and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @lc, i know.. I don't get it.. That's why i came to StackOverflow.. Obviously mmm

Comment: Your question is essentially the same as before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936345/listbox-and-database-issue. Same code, and same lack of precision as to what you are asking. I would advise maybe to think of it as if writing a bug report: what is happening with your code, what you would like to happen, and where/how you see the problem happening.

Comment: So this is not the actual code?  I bet ExecuteNonQuery throw an exception or returns a 0.   Your code does zero error checking.  -1

Comment: This is how they teach us at school ........

Comment: Also, your question is clearly not "What's the best way to INSERT data into a database?" - it is "I wrote code which doesn't work, can you help me fix it". You need to help people help you, by focusing on the exact problem you are having.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns one..

Comment: First it was "What's the best way to INSERT data into a database?"
But some people were asking if i have an instance, connection, ..
So I gave the full code ..

Comment: Prove it.  Post the code with try catch and the code you use to report the ExecuteNonQuery return count.  I don't believe you any more than I don't believe they teach not to error check at school.  No way that returns 1 and does not insert a row in the database.

Comment: Haha.. http://www.pictourl.com/viewer/d4e00017
It returns 1 and does not insert a row in the database : 
http://www.pictourl.com/viewer/42b020ef
BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAM.. Enough prove?

Comment: try
            {
                conn2.Open();
                int value = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn2.Close();
            }

Comment: HaHa two screen shots is not code

Comment: haha try { conn2.Open() .... is not code  .. right ..

Answer (score 57):

Try confirm the data type (**SqlDbType**) for each parameter in the database and do it this way;

```
 using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connSpionshopString"].ConnectionString))
 {
            connection.Open();
            string sql =  "INSERT INTO klant(klant_id,naam,voornaam) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection)) 
            {
                  cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = klantId;  
                  cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = klantNaam;
                  cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = klantVoornaam;
                  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
 }
```

Comment: If there was no conn2 then conn2.Open would fail.

Comment: In the Form_Load:
 conn2 = new SqlConnection();
            conn2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connSpionshopString"].ConnectionString; ?

Comment: You really do need to wrap that SqlCommand up in a `using` block just like the SqlConnection... otherwise you're looking at memory leaks up the patootie... :D

Answer (score 23):

you can use implicit casting **[`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx#Y0)**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", klantId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", klantNaam);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", klantVoornaam);
```

sample code,

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString")) 
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
    { 
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO klant(klant_id,naam,voornaam) 
                            VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";  

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", klantId);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", klantNaam);  
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", klantVoornaam);  

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            MessgeBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error Message");
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Also , the connection is not assigned to the cmd. Add cmd.connection = conn before conn.open();

Answer (score 3):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    connection.Open(); 
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) 
    { 
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO klant(klant_id,naam,voornaam) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";  

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", klantId));  
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", klantNaam));  
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", klantVoornaam));  

        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class customer
{
    public void InsertCustomer(string name,int age,string address)
    {
        // create and open a connection object
        using(SqlConnection Con=DbConnection.GetDbConnection())
        {
            // 1. create a command object identifying the stored procedure
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertCustomerData",Con);

            // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter();
            paramName.ParameterName = "@nvcname";
            paramName.Value = name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramName);

            SqlParameter paramAge = new SqlParameter();
            paramAge.ParameterName = "@inage";
            paramAge.Value = age;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAge);

            SqlParameter paramAddress = new SqlParameter();
            paramAddress.ParameterName = "@nvcaddress";
            paramAddress.Value = address;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAddress);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid hardcoding SQL statements in your application. If you don't use ADO nor EntityFramework, I would suggest you to ad a stored procedure to the database and call it from your c# application. A sample code can be found here: [How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-program) and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171921%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is "How do I insert into SQL using C#'s `sqlcommand` property (family)?". This should be a comment, at best.

Comment: My answer does not explain how to fix the issue described. I was myself curious why I answered like this 12 years ago ;). After looking at the question edits history, it seems that when I answered, the question was a lot shorter and the only snippet there was the first one (setting command text and adding params), so I suppose it made more sense then. I haven't edited it later to reflect subsequent question edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) library:

```
conn2.Execute(@"INSERT INTO klant(klant_id,naam,voornaam) VALUES (@p1,@p2,@p3)", 
                new { p1 = klantId, p2 = klantNaam, p3 = klantVoornaam });
```

BTW Dapper is a Stack Overflow project :)

UPDATE: I believe you can't do it simpler without something like EF. Also try to use `using` statements when you are working with database connections. This will close connection automatically, even in case of exception. And connection will be returned to connections pool.

```
private readonly string _spionshopConnectionString;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    _spionshopConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
          .ConnectionStrings["connSpionshopString"].ConnectionString;
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_spionshopConnectionString))
    {
         connection.Execute(@"INSERT INTO klant(klant_id,naam,voornaam) 
                              VALUES (@klantId,@klantNaam,@klantVoornaam)",
                              new { 
                                      klantId = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), 
                                      klantNaam = textBox2.Text, 
                                      klantVoornaam = textBox3.Text 
                                  });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AddWithValue()`, but be aware of the possibility of the wrong implicit type conversion.

like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", klantId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", klantNaam);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", klantVoornaam);
```