# Incorrect syntax near ','. SQL Server and c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am getting an exception:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

in following query: please help.

I have tried it in many ways but not it does not work. Even when I try to insert a single value I still get this exception.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into purchaseOrder_master(sup_id,po_date,required_date,tot_amt,uid,potime) values("+supid.Text +",'"+podate.Value.Date+"','"+reqdate.Value.Date+"',"+pocost.Text +","+uid.Text +",'"+potime.Value.TimeOfDay  +"')", con);
```

Comment: A small tip: Create the SQL string separately, then you can use a debugger to see its value (or just print it out). It will then, hopefully, be pretty obvious what's wrong with the SQL statement in the string. Or create the query using proper parameters as suggested otherwise.

Comment: first have to say this is not good way to insert record. u better use cmd.parameterd.add to pass parameters. then what is the data type of po_date?

Comment: @DevT po_date is datetime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How often do we have to repeat that you should use parameterized queries?!

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table (column) values (@param)", conn))
{
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", value);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The problems with your code are:

1. Wide open to SQL injections
2. DateTime values will not be handled correctly (probably the problem right now)
3. Strings must be handled properly (quotes)

Comment: For ever.  New users to SQL won't have heard you the other times.  Frustrating, but `I've told a hundred other people this!` isn't really going to matter to the 101st user...  :(

Comment: I know. The question is rather rhetoric. Just as the question *Why didn't you search SO before asking a question that has been asked 100 times?*.

Comment: Because new users don't even know what to search for. :(

Comment: @MatBailie That is sort of a rediculous point, don't you think?

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar Thank you so much for your suggestions now onwards i will use parametrized queries and thanks for quick response.

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you so much for understanding the problem of new users.

Comment: @MatBailie I'd like to elaborate a bit why I think your point is not valid: It's not a matter of whether you know how to use SO or not. Every programmer should be able to use Google to search for solutions to his problems. Usually you would start with a very specific query, which then gets broader and broader until you find a result that helps you. The Google query *C# SqlCommand INSERT exception* brings up this as first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939501/insert-into-c-sharp-with-sqlcommand. So if you can't even Google properly...?

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PurchaseOrder_master(sup_id) values(@val)", con);    
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@val", supid.Text );
```

please check data type of date as well. it seems you passing just string for this. if its date time then you need parse string to datetime.
 for that conversion use,

```
 DateTime.Parse("stringValue");
```

if you want to save it without command parameters, then convert your date value and check as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your **actual** SQL string.

Probably one of your values is an empty string.

That, and what Thorsten said. Use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"+uid.Text +"
```

to

```
'"+uid.Text +"'
```

and

```
"+supid.Text +"
```

to

```
'"+supid.Text +"'
```

so that

```
values("+supid.Text +",'"+podate.Value.Date+"','"+reqdate.Value.Date+"',"+pocost.Text +","+uid.Text +",'"+potime.Value.TimeOfDay  +"')
```

reads

```
values('"+supid.Text +"','"+podate.Value.Date+"','"+reqdate.Value.Date+"',"+pocost.Text +",'"+uid.Text +"','"+potime.Value.TimeOfDay  +"')
```

Comment: No, don't do that. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I don't argue about being right or wrong. But there are times you just cannot do otherwise. SO has expressed a specific issue, and this resolves it. He didn't ask if it is right or wrong...

Comment: And I tend to point people, who's code is showing deeper problems than just the one they want a solution for, to a better solution. Using parameterized queries here solves his problem as well as your solution (probably), but also resolves most other problems. If you ask me why your bubble sort implementation doesn't work, I will tell you, but I'll also tell you why bubble sort is not a good idea.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar The reason i haven't actually delete my post is because it really gives another point of view. For instance, it is good to show the asker what the problem is. From your point of view the problem is that he is not using parameterized queries. That doesn't explain though why he got his error... Keeping this post live will at least show him what else was wrong apart from a wrong approach.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar agreed to what you have pointed out, but if you have downvoted for this, then i think it is unfair. Because, the question is not for code review. it is for solution and this does resolves the issue. obviously not the best way, but it does.

Comment: @NoOne Valid point, I'm taking back the downvote, as it does solve the issue (sorry, I had to edit the answer slightly so I could take back the downvote).

Comment: @jyparask and All of you really helped me to learn something from all your answers and comments. Thank you again...

Answer (score 0):

i believe the problem is you are putting strings in the insert statement without "'" signs

try:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into purchaseOrder_master(sup_id,po_date,required_date,tot_amt,uid,potime) values("+supid.Text +",'"+podate.Value.Date+"','"+reqdate.Value.Date+"','"+pocost.Text +"','"+uid.Text +"','"+potime.Value.TimeOfDay  +"')", con);
```

as you can read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp), when doing insert statement, every string needs to be surround with "'"

Comment: There's almost no proper way of inserting a `DateTime` into the database using concatenated strings. You need to convert it to US date format first, which is not always given. Also I suggest you don't encourage him, but suggest using parameterized queries, as this is the only sane way of dealing with database queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your code and check what exactly the query is formed.

Also i think the possible reason is

```
insert into purchaseOrder_master(sup_id,po_date,required_date,tot_amt,**uid**,potime
```

uid is a keyword. replace it with [uid] and check

Answer (score -1):

You have a string.empty in yours variables. Suddenly you generate the following commande :
insert into purchaseOrder_master(sup_id,po_date,required_date,tot_amt,uid,potime) values('value1','value2',,'value3'...

you can use string.format to format your command

Comment: i am not the downvoter. but i would recommend that you update your answer with some solution. it does highlight the issue.