# How to insert data to the database using a list (List<Object>) of objects and modals?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Hi all I'm trying to insert some values to the database using mvc in asp.net. I heard that it would be good use objects when inserting data. So How can I achieve this using a List of objects through properties designed in a class.

Have a class called,

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public int Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

So I have a another class which simply do the sql commands

DBAccess.cs

```
public List<Customer> AddCustomers(string spName)
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = spName;
        }
```

I know that using Idata Reader using can get the values in a database like this

```
IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Customer cus = new Customer();

                cus.Name = reader["cus_name"].ToString();
                cus.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["cid"]);

                customers.Add(cus);
            }
```

How do I insert data back to the database using such a scenario? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it update or insert? DataTable can be saved in database easily using SqlBulkCopy

Comment: @Sami Insert data to database :)

Comment: @AshaneAlvis. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12939934/4873601

Comment: you can write one **StoredProcedure**  for insert

Comment: @AwaisMahmood I wanted to know that if we can achieve this using a List of objects Like `List<Customer> `

Comment: @Paarth I normally did like that. Wanted to try a new method.

Comment: @AshaneAlvis. so u wanted to pass the List<Customer> to the method and you want that method to create the insert command dynamically??

Comment: @AwaisMahmood yes that would seem right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row

Comment: You should use Table-Valued Parameters ( TVP ). Please see my answer to [Pass Dictionary<string,int> to Stored Procedure T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25815939/577765) for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the base you have to make an SQL insert command to insert into DB. So, you could try the following. This method will get the list and table name as a parameter. Inside the loop reflection is used to insert the values in key value pair list.

```
public static bool Insert(List<YourModel> datas, string table)
{
    bool result = false;
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
    con.Open();

    try
    {
        foreach (var data in datas)
        {

            values.Clear();
            foreach (var item in data.GetType().GetProperties())
            {          
                 values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Name, item.GetValue(data).ToString()));
            }

            string xQry = getInsertCommand(table, values);
            SqlCommand cmdi = new SqlCommand(xQry, con);
            cmdi.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        result = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { throw ex; }
    finally { con.Close(); }
    return result;
}
```

In the following method the key value pair list will be passed to another function to make the insert command.

```
private static string getInsertCommand(string table, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values)
{
    string query = null;
    query += "INSERT INTO " + table + " ( ";
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        query += item.Key;
        query += ", ";
    }
    query = query.Remove(query.Length - 2, 2);
    query += ") VALUES ( ";
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        if (item.Key.GetType().Name == "System.Int") // or any other numerics
        {
            query += item.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            query += "'";
            query += item.Value;
            query += "'";
        }
        query += ", ";
    }
    query = query.Remove(query.Length - 2, 2);
    query += ")";
    return query;
}
```