# Cannot Find Table 0 from other form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tried to move data from one form to another and there is a problem with the table. Yes I found such themes with a mistake, and tried to correct himself, but something went wrong.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-R552818\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Fond;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    SqlDataAdapter comm = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO Pacient (Name, id_diagnoz, Surname, Middle_name, Column__Passport, Legal_address_Clinic, Age) " +
                "VALUES ('"+ tName.Text + "', (SELECT id_diagnoz FROM Diagnoz WHERE Name_diagnoz = '" + cbName.Text + "' and Stage = '" + cbStage.Text + "'), '" + tSurname.Text + "', '" + tMiddle.Text + "', '" + tPas.Text + "', '" + cbClinic.Text + "', '" + tAge.Text + "')", conn);
    conn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
    comm.Fill(ds);

    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.DataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; //?
}
```

---

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-R552818\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Fond;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                try
                {                        
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Pacient (Name, id_diagnoz, Surname, Middle_name, Column__Passport, Legal_address_Clinic, Age) " +
                "VALUES ('" + metroTextBox1.Text + "', (SELECT id_diagnoz FROM Diagnoz WHERE Name_diagnoz = '" + metroComboBox1.Text + "' and Stage = '" + metroComboBox2.Text + "'), '" + metroTextBox2.Text + "', '" + metroTextBox3.Text + "', '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "', '" + metroComboBox3.Text + "', '" + metroTextBox5.Text + "')";

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
                    transaction.Commit();
                    MessageBox.Show("Added");  
                   //here is a DataSet                                              
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }

            }
```

Comment: First of all, use [Parameterized queries](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter). Second: did you run your code inside SQL, does it return anything (I feet, that it doesn't)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting results to be returned from your query, but what you do is just `INSERT` statement.

For inserting values you should use `ExecuteNonQuery` method of `SqlCommand` ([see this for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939501/insert-into-c-sharp-with-sqlcommand)).

Then, assign another command: `SELECT` to get the results, then you can fill `DataSet` with the result and then you can fill `DataGridView` with it.

**Also**: you are rpone to SQL injection, use parametrized query to prevent yourself from such threat ([see this for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Comment: I've made some changes as you say. But i can not use now .Fill, maybe need again to reconnect SqlDataAdapter for this? Or another way

Comment: @Yippeeki-yay No, you call `Fill` when executing `SELECT` statement. With your current code: after `ExecuteNonQuery` you assign another SQL command: `SELECT` statement, then you proceed as usual, using `Fill` method.