# Windows Server 2003 R2 Directory Connection Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, winforms, networking

I am trying with this application to read a **.jpg** file on a remote Server
Windows Server 2003 R2.

For this in a **WebForm** project occupy **NetworkConnection**

Intuitively I have given value to some parameters that are occupied but I have doubt with them

`using (NetworkConnection nc = new NetworkConnection(localName, networkName, objnetCred))`

localName =  "F:"                            **<< I doubt where I can find this value in my network 
                                                   and which it would be its format**

networkName = "servidor_99"                 **<< I doubt where I can find this value in my network and 
                                               which it would be its format**

objnetCred =

Domain   "999.999.99.999"                     **<< I doubt where I can find this value in my network 
                                                   and which it would be its format**

Password "xxxxxxxxxx"

UserName "usernamexxx"

```
var result = WNetAddConnection2(
            netResource,
            credentials.Password,
            credentials.UserName,
            flags);
```

netResource

Comment           null

Display Type      Share

LocalName         "F:"

Provider          null

RemoteName        "servidor_99"

ResourceType      Disk

Scope             GlobalNetwork

Usage             0

credentials.Password          "xxxxxxxxxx"

credentials.UserName          "usernamexxx"

flags                         1

**With these values ​​I get the error:**

The result value is equal to **67**

**The specified network name is not found**

I would appreciate some guidance in this regard

Regards

Comment: Windows Server 2003 hit end of life back in 2015 - why are you still using it? It's not receiving security updates - that's a big security risk.

Comment: Im wrong the posible solution at my proyect maybe thats here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939501/insert-into-c-sharp-with-sqlcommand