# how to access output values of Select instance in LINQ in a C# program

Tags: c#, sql, linq, c#-4.0

I am new to writing Stored Procedure. So I wrote below procedure and want to access the output values in my program, hot to do it.

My Stored Procedure:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[STP_ExecCarInDriver_SelectByCarCode]
@CarCode nchar(10)
As
Begin

SELECT DISTINCT
[MachineName]
,[FirstName]
,[LastName]
FROM [RoadTrs].[dbo].[ViewExecCarInDriver]
WHERE [CarCode]=@CarCode

End
```

and try with below code to instance to MachineName,FirstName and Last Name parameters:

```
var Results = rt.STP_ExecCarInDriver_SelectByCarCode(txtCarCode.Text);
string MachineName= Results(0).
```

but it doesn't work !

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-program) may help.

Comment: Are you using ADO, Link To Entities, linq to sql?

Comment: What is your `rt` object? Are you using LINQ to SQL? or what? How does C# know about your stored procedure?

Comment: Farzad M have you looked at this link perhaps this may help [How to Execute Stored Procedure from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-program)

Comment: @DJKRAZE - Copy cat!  :P

Comment: No Brian I actually think that it's easier to format a link opposed to putting try `this` for example the OP may not know it's an actual link.. LOL

Comment: yes rt is the object of linq data class

Answer (score 1):

if you are using LinqtoSql i would advise against using the stored proceedure at all 
(they become a pain in the arse to manage imho)

instead use the data context to get the item

```
int carcode = 0; //input your code here

var ctx = new RoadTrsDataContext();
var item - ctx.ViewExecCarInDriver.Where(x=>x.CarCode == carcode).FirstOrDefault();
ctx.Dispose();

if(item!= null)
{
var name = item.FirstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
        var Results = rt.STP_ExecCarInDriver_SelectByCarCode(txtCarCode.Text).FirstOrDefault();//Use .List() if query return more than one result.
        string MachineName = Results.MachineName;
        string FirstName = Results.FirstName;
        string LastName = Results.LastName;
```

Comment: it is not work because don't have any .FirstOrDefault() function