# Database.ExecuteSqlCommand always returns -1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a EF code-first model. It is working fine, but when I try to run a stored procedure with `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` it always returns -1, it doesn't matter what I put in the stored procedure result is always -1

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Login_user] 
    @clientKey varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    RETURN(0)
END
```

And I run it like:

```
return Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(EXEC [dbo].[Login_user] {0}", key);
```

Am I missing something?

By the way if I run the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio it returns 0

```
USE [lo9iMed]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Login_user]
    @clientKey = N'76F41F99-EA9E-4181-A6FB-579D23D3C2C0'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Thanks in advance.

anibal

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program)

Answer (score 5):

You have the SET NOCOUNT ON directive included in your stored procedure (you probably used the SSMS template?).  This means it will not count the rows affected by your commands. Remove this line and you should be good to go! :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `SELECT`, what you want is `ExecuteScalar` - or if that isn't exposed, `SqlQuery<int>`. You *might* get the result you are after if you change it to `return @return_value;` - but then: you might not.

Comment: Hi Marc thx, 4 your answer. I've tried
ExecuteQuery<int>("EXEC [dbo].[Login_user] {0}", key) and it throws
 The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: @user2968933 frankly, whatever this `Database` wrapper is here: it isn't helping you...