# Why I'm getting Incorrect syntax near ')' error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, syntax

I'm trying to create a registration page using C# on Visual Basic 2012. When I debug I get 0 errors, but when I try to register an account I get the following error.

> "Incorrect syntax near ')'"

If I try to create an account with an existing username it says that username already exist. So I'm able to connect to the SQL server, but I'm not sure where I went wrong.

This registration page should create accounts in my DB DNMembership> Table> Accounts

Here is my code I'm working with.

```
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegDNMembershipConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    string insCmd = "Insert into Accounts (AccountName, Passphrase, EmailAddress, FullName, Country)";
    SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", TextBoxUN.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passphrase", TextBoxPass.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", TextBoxEA.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBoxFN.Text);
    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());

    try
    {
        insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
    catch(Exception er)
    {
        Response.Write("<b>Something Really Bad Happened... Please Try Again.< /br></b>");
        Response.Write(er.Message);
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to master SQL. It is only executed on runtime. You won't get any compiler error for SQL syntax in a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you forget to add `VALUES` part in your [`INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ms174335.aspx) command.

> VALUES
>   Introduces the list or lists of data values to be inserted. **There must
>   be one data value for each column in column_list, if specified, or in
>   the table**. The value list must be enclosed in parentheses.

Change your sql query like;

```
string insCmd = @"Insert into Accounts (AccountName, Passphrase, EmailAddress, FullName, Country)
                 VALUES(@AccountName, @Passphrase, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country)";
```

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` like;

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegDNMembershipConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{    
   using(SqlCommand insertUser = new...)
   {
     //Your code..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified any parameters in your SQL, or a `VALUES` section - you're saying "I want to insert into these fields..." but not *what* you want to insert. It should be something like:

```
string insCmd =
   "Insert into Accounts (AccountName, Passphrase, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) "
 + "Values (@AccountName, @Passphrase, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the SQL statement:

```
string insCmd = "Insert into Accounts (AccountName, Passphrase, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) VALUES (@AccountName,@Passphrase,@EmailAddress,@FullName,@Country)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing part of `Insert` statement

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (@col1, @col2)
```

Or if you want to insert all values into columns in order they are in table

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (@col1, @col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several alternatives for `INSERT` command in SQL Server.

- Specify `COLUMNS` and after that specify `VALUES`
- - **SQL Syntax** - `INSERT INTO TABLE(AccountName, Passphrase, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) 
    VALUES ('AccountName', 'Passphrase', 'EmailAddress', 'FullName', 'Country')`
- - **C#** `string insCmd = "INSERT INTO TABLE(AccountName, Passphrase, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) 
    VALUES (@AccountName, @Passphrase, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country)"`
- If you are sure about the order of columns you can skip specifying columns, this can be risky in case you screw up order of `VALUES` you will insert values into wrong columns
- - **SQL Sytanx** - `INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('AccountName', 'Passphrase', 'EmailAddress', 'FullName', 'Country')`
- - **C#** `string insCmd = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (@AccountName, @Passphrase, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country)"`

Good resources to read would be

- W3School - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp
- Technet - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx

Alternative to `INSERT INTO TABLE` you can call stored procedures from `C#` that inserts into table. Use of stored procedures can help you reduce ad-hoc queries, help prevent SQL injection, reduce network traffic, add additional validation server side. Your code will look as follows.

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertIntoAccount", con);
con.Open();

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccountName", TextBoxUN.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Passphrase", TextBoxPass.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", TextBoxEA.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FullName", TextBoxFN.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString()));

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
catch(Exception er)
{
    Response.Write("<b>Something Really Bad Happened... Please Try Again.< /br></b>");
    Response.Write(er.Message);
}
```

Additional resources are listed on answer at the following questions [How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program)