# Using a stored procedure in a dynamic data web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-dynamic-data

This is homework assignment that isn't covered in our books and we were instructed to use the internet and/or any other resources to figure out this assignment.  The information I'm finding on the web is a little over my head and was hoping for a more laymen explanation!!

I have an existing asp.net web site using c#, without issue I was able to add dynamic data capabilities to my site by creating a dummy site, hooked up to AdventureWorks DB, and adding the appropriate files and assemblies to my existing site.

This is where I am getting lost.  I need to use one of the stored procedures in the Adventure Works DB to display data on a page.  I am attempting to use the uspGetEmployeeManagers by associating it with a listview on my aspx page.  This is pretty much as far as I can get.  All the blogs I've read are a little over my head and I've become more confused than when I started.

Can someone please explain to me, as simply as possible, what I need to do to display data using a stored procedure in a dynamic data web site?

Thank you!

Code:

```
    protected void getEmployeeManagers(int employeeID)
{
    AdventureWorksLTDataContext aventureWorksDataContext = new AdventureWorksLTDataContext();

    var dynamicData = aventureWorksDataContext.uspGetEmployeeManagers(employeeID);

    lvwGetEmployeeManager.DataSource = dynamicData;
    lvwGetEmployeeManager.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: post the code how you tried using SP

Comment: @EhsanSajjad code is posted.

Comment: what are you doing in method uspGetEmployeeManagers??

Comment: I should also note that I am still very very novice when it comes to asp.net, this hasn't been a technology that has come naturally to me..kind of an uphill battle with this class.  So to answer your question, idk!!

Comment: What is showing up in the listview or lvwGetEmployeeManager, whatever it is?  The term "var"should work but I would stick to using "DataTable" or "DataSet" for loading.

Comment: Nothing is showing up.  The page loads without error, but it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any data source you want for the most part.  You need to hook up the data to the listview correctly.  Here an example:

Markup

```
    <div id= "Test1a" class="fieldgroup" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="panelWithHistoryControl" runat="server">            
        <asp:ListView ID="test1" runat="server" OnLoad="test1_OnLoad">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="test1PlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# Eval("Column1")%></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Column2")%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>           
    </asp:Panel></div>
```

Column1 and Column2 are the table columns or interface property names etc.

Code Behind

```
public void test1_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    var list = // Get your data from the database.  Return as an IList<T> or something   
               //similar.

    test1.DataSource = list;
    test1.ItemPlaceholderID = "test1PlaceHolder";
    test1.DataBind();
}
```

References
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemtemplate.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153238/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122607-1.aspx

Finally, executing stored procedures from C# is fairly straight forward. There are many sources See:
[How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399407(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx