# Using dropdown selected value as parameter in an update query, update not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to use the selected value from a dropdown as a parameter in a update query to update the name for that selected item, but the update query doesn't work. The dropdown is bounded and extracts data from a sql table,the new name is captured from a textfield.  Here is my code:

```
protected void UpdateName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
     {
          SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("update z_SignAssets set signAsset =@asset where signAssetID =@id",con);
          int dropdownValue = Convert.ToInt32(SignAssetDropDown.SelectedValue);

          da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@asset", newNameTextField.Text); 
          da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dropdownValue);               
          UpdateName.Visible = false;
          newNameTextField.Visible = false;
          checkcost.Visible = true;
          EditName.Visible = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is it all of your code? In my knowledge this is not how SqlAdapter works. Did you read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This should definitely be outside of your sql using statements, they do not pertain to updating data but to UI elements: `UpdateName.Visible = false;
          newNameTextField.Visible = false;
          checkcost.Visible = true;
          EditName.Visible = true;`

Comment: I got it solved, realized i was using selectCommand, the updateCommand with ExecuteNonQuery should be the one. Thanks,

Comment: And take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1260961/855916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a SelectCommand instead of an UpdateCommand in your code. Also it could just be an SQLCommand. You do not need to use a SqlDataAdapter here. Also where are you executing non query or executing the command which is shown below with ExecuteNonQuery?

```
int dropdownValue = Convert.ToInt32(SignAssetDropDown.SelectedValue);

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{        
    SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand("update z_SignAssets set signAsset =@asset where signAssetID =@id",con);

    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@asset", newNameTextField.Text); 
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dropdownValue);               
    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();        
}
UpdateName.Visible = false;
newNameTextField.Visible = false;
checkcost.Visible = true;
EditName.Visible = true;
```

Comment: yea i figured out yesterday i was using the wrong thing, but thanks very much for responding :)