# Insert multiple records using stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

```
emplyoee (first table)
id primary key auto increment
emp_name varchar

student(second table)
id foriegnkey emplyoee.id
st_name varchar
```

I want to insert multiple student records for a single `employeeid` . My code is attached here , but this use to only one student record update. How can I write stored procedure for this need.
I am new with SQL server and stored procedure.

Could you please help me?

```
create procedure  empst_Sp
@emp_name varchar(50),
@st_name varchar(50)
as
begin
insert into emplyoee (emp_name) values (@emp_name)
insert into student(id,st_name) values(SCOPE_IDENTITY(),@st_name)
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by multiple student records? What would be the value of `st_name` for these multiple records? Show us how you're calling the SP.

Comment: is it possible to add  one primary key use insert more than one foriegnkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, you can try this code above ( I'm using XML parameter type)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmployeeIns
  @EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50),
  @Students XML
AS
/*
  @Students : <Students>
                  <Student Name='Studen 1'/>
                  <Student Name='Studen 1'/>
              </Students>
*/
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StudenTable TABLE(Name NVARCHAR(50))
    DECLARE @EmployeeId INT

    INSERT INTO @StudenTable
    SELECT Tbl.Col.value('@Name', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
    FROM @Students.nodes('//Student') Tbl(Col)

    INSERT INTO Emplyoee VALUES(@EmployeeName)
    SET @EmployeeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Student 
    SELECT @EmployeeId, Name FROM @StudenTable
END
```

**Update 1 :**
Your table design should be look like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emplyoee](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Emplyoee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
    [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))
```

The execute code :

```
EXEC EmployeeIns @EmployeeName='trungtin1710', @Students = '<Students><Student Name="Studen 1"/><Student Name="Studen 1"/></Students>'
```

Comment: data  not passing to student table

Comment: @UnniR pls check update 1, you should change the schema of your Student table

Comment: @UnniR you should search around the internet, there are a lot of topic for this.
For example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program

Answer (score 0):

As I understand:
 If emplyoee  with @emp_name is already exists then insert student records with ID of the emplyoee, if there is not any emplyoee with @emp_name  then need to insert new emplyoee and student with ID of the new emplyoee. Yes?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE empst_Sp
@emp_name varchar(50),
@st_name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @EmplyoeeId  int
    SET @EmplyoeeId = NULL

    select @EmplyoeeId = id 
    from   emplyoee 
    where  emp_name = @emp_name

    IF @EmplyoeeId IS NULL
    BEGIN
      insert into emplyoee (emp_name) values (@emp_name)
      SET @EmplyoeeId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    insert into student(id, st_name) values(@EmplyoeeId, @st_name)
END
```

Comment: Yes, same id (Employee)use to insert more than student.

Comment: Ok, please try this code. The code need to refactor for more beautiful view if it work

Comment: I want to insert at a time more than one value in student table using primary key .

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a `local variable` in which you can set the value retrieved from Scope_Identity:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE empst_Sp
@emp_name varchar(50),
@st_name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @id INT
INSERT INTO emplyoee (emp_name) VALUES (@emp_name)
set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO student(id,st_name) VALUES (@id,@st_name)
END
```