# How to find the empty cells in the datatable and replace with 0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

I am working with a very large datatable which has 5000 rows and 8000 columns. In the data table there are some empty cells. I use the following code to fill the empty cells with 0. But since the datatable is very large, the speed is really slow!!! I just want to ask if there are some other ways instead of the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SP_dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SP_dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (SP_dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() == "")
            SP_dt.Rows[i][j] = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}",i,j);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any faster way if you are using DataTable. Maybe you should consider SQL if your task allows so? Also you may try removing WriteLine - if you call it every time, it will greatly impact performance.

Comment: I can remove console.writeline. But I don't think this will help much

Comment: is it WinForms of WPF?

Comment: it is console application

Comment: This should be done via SQL.  SQL works on set-based operations and is lightning fast compared to anything you can do on the code-side to replicate (and, it's pretty easy... if you have actual T-SQL, `COALESCE(ColumnName, 0)` is the function you need)

Comment: Can you give some more details for SQL. I haven't used that before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is better solved in the SQL than in C# code, create a stored procedure for your query, and then use `COALESCE` system function.

The `COALESCE` function will basically check a set of elements given in its arguments from the left to right till it finds that it is not `NULL` and returns it. This way, you could put your default value `0` in the last element of `COALESCE`:

```
create procedure spMyProc
as
begin
  select 
    COALESCE(colName1HavingNumericDataTypeToBeChecked, 0),
    COALESCE(colName2HavingNumericDataTypeToBeChecked, 0), 
    COALESCE(colNameNHavingNumericDataTypeToBeChecked, 0) 
  from tableName
end
```

Then in your C# code, you just [call that stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program).

If your `colName1HavingNumericDataTypeToBeChecked` is not `NULL`, it will return the value in the `colName1HavingNumericDataTypeToBeChecked`. If it is `NULL`, then it will look up the next item and find `0` (which is not `NULL`) and it will return `0`.

Comment: A stored procedure is hardly necessary... `COALESCE()` can be used in any "regular" query as well (that said, it's not necessarily bad to use a sproc, just figured I'd point out that it's not required).

Comment: @jdl134679 I agree that stored procedure is not *necessary* here, but it is *more efficient*, as the OP wants. If we use regular query, the execution plan will be created multiple times - and thus adding more time overhead. But if we use stored procedure, the execution plan will only be created once - and thus more efficient. ;)

Comment: If the resultant text of the compiled query doesn't change between calls, the plan is only created once and subsequent calls use a cached plan.  Of course a procedure does guarantee this, but my argument is more in that OP is clearly not a SQL guru and the idea of a stored procedure might be a step more involved than he'd like :)  Cheers