# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified, C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am developing my very first stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 and need advice concerning the error message I get.

C# code:

[image: my code in C#]

Stored procedure code:

[image: my procedure that use in my C# code]

Comment: You should copy-paste your code, would be better.

Comment: You should post the **code as code (text)** - not as screenshots !

Answer (score 0):

In the example you showed, you are not using the stored procedure.  The whole Program.sqlcmd.CommandType isn't being used, as you specify a different SQL string (st) to use.

You need to look at examples of how to do stored procedures from c#.

[How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program)