# How get return value from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, return-value, sybase

I have an SP that returns integer value. The SP hasn't defined any return variable and it is directly returning value for e.g. return -1, return -2

I tried the following code but it gives exception:

**Code**

> AseParameter retval = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE",
>   SqlDbType.Int);   retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
>   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    //This line throws exception

**Exception**

> NotSupportException
>
> BindParameter - Int

How to read return value?

**EDIT**

Stored Procedure

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MySP') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.MySP
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MySP') IS NOT NULL
        PRINT '<<< FAILED DROPPING PROCEDURE dbo.MySP >>>'
    ELSE
        PRINT '<<< DROPPED PROCEDURE dbo.MySP >>>'
END
go
create procedure MySP

    @param1         char(60),
    @param2         char(3),
    @param3           int,
    @param4         char(4)  
as
declare
    @somefield1          char(1),
    @somefield2           datetime,

    If @param1 is null
        return -1

    If @param2 != "L"
        return -2

more code here.....
```

Comment: Did you try to set a value? _AseParameter retval = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;_

Comment: Getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseParameter'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Could you show the code of SP? and more code to run the SP?

Comment: SP coded added above.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following code fixed the issue. I realized that I was passing `SqlDbType.Int` when this is actually Sybase ASE database.

```
AseParameter retval = new AseParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", AseDbType.Integer);
cmd.Parameters.Add(retval);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
return (int)cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a sqldatareader, given that you're hoping to get a value back.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program/1260998#1260998) has the code already written out for you. Just needs adapted to your case. There are also a few good links to some pretty decent learning materials.