# Execute stored procedure using table adapter in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In VB.net I can simply execute a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 using the query in image below, but in C# I got an error.

Can you help me about the proper syntax in C#?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Show us the actual VB code, not the VB code pasted into a C# class.

Comment: Instead of posting screenshot of code post the actua code .

Comment: this is the code in C#, I am using data bind

Comment: already solved!

Comment: textBox3.Text = this.tbl_UsersTableAdapter.getUser(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text);

Comment: How did you solve it @DaveesJohnBaclay ?

Comment: you don't need to include the field names such as username and password unlike in Vb,

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(your-connection-string)) {
conn.Open();

// 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("your-procedure-name", conn);

// 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", textBox1.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", textBox2.Text));

// execute the command
using (SqlDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    // iterate through results, printing each to console
    while (result .Read())
    {
      // Name  and Password Should Match with your proc col name 
      var userName  = result["Name"].toString();
      var password  = result["password"].toString();

    }
}
 }
```

For More details Please Read this this

[How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program)