# How to save a procedure against a database in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

So i'm following a tutorial on how to connect a database to WFA and at this step he saves the procedure, but don't know where because he skips.

My question: How do I save it inside the folder because whenever I want to save, it wants me to choose a path and doesn't save directly in the "Stored Procedures" folder.

[image]

Comment: Just create it :)

Comment: You don't need to save the `SP` in the folder or even choose a path for that, all what you need is targeting the right database, create your `SP` and excute the code.

Comment: An obvious thing to most, but maybe handy for the person asking: What you are trying to save is a text file that holds code. If you place a 'create procedure'-line above (as shown below) and execute the code, the procedure is created (saved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question `SQL SERVER` automatically saves your stored procedures within the **Programmability** -> **Stored Procedures** -> **Your SP** upon creation.

**Note** : Always remember to refresh the `Stored Procedures` Folder after you have created a new Stored Procedure, otherwise you might not be able to see it (but its there, dont worry)

**UPDATE**

Here is a `TSQL` statement to create a Stored Procedure (of course you can change it to your own vision) :

```
USE YourDatabaseName
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SchemaName.SPName
AS
SELECT * FROM SchemaName.TableName
GO
```

This will Create a Simple SP for your service (assuming you have excuted it). Now can look for it as above.

**Remember** You need to look for it within your `SQL Server Management Studio`. not within Visual Studio (Which you will be able to Call the SP later within your C# code using An **ORM**)

Comment: Tried to refresh, but it's empty every time, i really don't know how to fix this. Being newbie sucks

Comment: @Elsawhere Be sure that you targeting the correct database.

Comment: @Elsawhere Lets Create a new SP. and see if this works. See my update in a bit, Also as Sami said besure that you are targeting the correct Database

Comment: @Elsawhere Also tell me which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: Am i allowed to link the yt video that i'm following to see exactly what i mean? Because i don't understand much of these, i never used Sql server and btw it is the 2017 version

Comment: @Elsawhere sure gimme the link.

Comment: @Elsawhere You need to install SQL Server Management Studio and its Node. First as well do you have it installed already?

Comment: It appeared! I created a new database, wrote what you said in SSMS and when I added the database in Server Explorer, the store procedure appread and now I can modify it :D. Voodoo for me

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are creating a procedure like below

```
CREATE PROC Test
AS 
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

If you write this in SQL Server Management Studio and Execute (F5) against a DB, this will come under **Programmability -> Stored Procedures**.

Just execute the code and refresh the DB in Object Explorer and check under

```
Programmability -> Stored Procedures
```

**OR**

If you are trying to create the procedure from  **C# code**, Just execute it like normal sql query through the C# code against the DB.

This will also create a procedure under `Programmability -> Stored Procedures`. Check SSMS in the same way as above to see.

**OR**

If you are trying to execute a stored procedure through C# code refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program)