# Calling stored procedure with parameter to return list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure with parameters, which i want to submit the parameters in a view which returns a index of the list. How do i go about this in my controller

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spFlugReport]     
(      
   @AccNo INTEGER,
   @DateFrom DATE, 
   @DateTo DATE    
)      
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[KIRData] 
    WHERE AccNo = @AccNo 
      AND StartDate >= @DateFrom 
      AND EndDate <= @DateTo 
      AND Prod = 'Air'
END
```

C# code:

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
    using(DataModel db = new DataModel())
    {
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[] {
            new SqlParameter("@AccNo ,"),
            new SqlParameter("@DateFrom ,"),
            new SqlParameter("@DateTo ,")
        };


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please, can you explain more clearly what you want? From what you've said, I can't understand what you want.

Comment: i want to pass parameters to my stored procedure to return a list

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow. Here is a useful link that could help you to achieve what you need to do.

https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson07

and here is one with a similar question to your problem [How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program)

However, here is an quick example of what you need to pass a parameter to a stored procedure.

```
// create and open a connection object
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
conn.Open();

// 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("CustOrderHist", conn);

// 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custId));

// execute the command
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this. If not, could you provide more detail.

```
DataTable database = new DataTable();
string dbString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spFlugReport", con))
{
    using(DataModel db = new DataModel())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccNo", AccNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", DateFrom);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", DateTo);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();               
    }
}
```

This link is how you created a ConnectionString  for `YourConnection`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string