# How to pass json value to stored procedure in node js

Tags: c#, node.js, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which contains one "user defined table type" parameter in Microsoft SQL Server. I am passing "Data Table" as parameter value to the stored procedure in C#. I would like to know how to pass Json data from node js as "Data Table" to this stored procedure.

User-defined table type :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TpUserRights] AS TABLE
                                    (
                                        [ConfigId] [int] NULL,
                                        [FormId] [int] NOT NULL
                                    )
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpMergeUserRights] 
    (@UserRights TpUserRights ReadOnly) 
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE ModuleUserConfig AS [Target]
    USING @UserRights AS [Source] ON [Target].ConfigId = [Source].ConfigId

    WHEN NOT MATCHE BY TARGET
       THEN
           INSERT (ModuleId, FormId, UserId, CreatedBy) 
           VALUES (@ModuleId, [Source].FormId, @UserId, @CreatedBy) 

    WHEN MATCHED
       THEN 
           UPDATE 
           SET FormId = [Source].FormId,
               UserId = @UserId, 
               ModifiedDate = GETDATE(),
               ModifiedBy = @CreatedBy;
END
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program

Comment: I know how to pass value in store procedure in C# code but my question is how to pass json value to store procedure in node js

Comment: You have to parse the value(s) out of the JSON string.  You can using JSON deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple in SQL Server 2016 and later. Just pass JSON as a string to SQL Server and parse it to load the TVP on the server.  See [Work with JSON data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).  And from JavaScript this is the best way to pass bulk data to SQL Server.

On older SQL Server versions, for clients without Table-Valued Parameter support you can use XML, load a temp table, or just call the procedure like this:

```
declare @rights as TpUserRights

insert into @rights(ConfigId,FormId) 
values (@ConfigId,@FormId)

exec SpMergeUserRights @rights
```

binding parameters for `@ConfigId` and `@FormId`.  And either binding additional parameters for more rows, or calling the procedure multiple times.