# Map only 2 specific stored procedure and a table in linq2db t4

Tags: c#, linq2db

I've a quite huge database,which scripted with t4 generates around 30k lines of code. Since this application only uses 2 stored procedure, is there a way to tell at t4 generator to process just the specific stored procedure name I need to map?

I know I can manually delete the remaing but it would be easier to just create them

Comment: You can create needed POCO's by hand without T4, I assume.

Comment: You can call directly stored proc. without ORM https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260961/4429029

Comment: I know but since I would have to mamually map data its best to use an orm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After metadata load (`Load*Metadata` call) you should add code to go over all procedures and remove all except those you need

```cs
foreach (var p in Procedures.ToList())
        if (p.Value.ProcedureName != "put_your_name_here")
            Procedures.Remove(p.Key);
```