# Can't backup a SQL Server database using stored proc from .Net c# program but same proc in ssms works fine

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wrote a SQL Server stored procedure to backup a database:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_backup_database]
    (@DBName sysname = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF LEN (ISNULL (@DBName, '')) > 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) = 'D:\MSSQL\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\';
        DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256);
        DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(50) = REPLACE (CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), GETDATE (), 126), ':', '-');

        SET @fileName = @path + @DBName + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK';

        BEGIN TRY
            BACKUP DATABASE @DBName 
            TO DISK = @fileName WITH COMPRESSION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
            DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
            DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

            SELECT 
                @ErrorMessage  = @fileName + N' ' + ERROR_MESSAGE (),
                @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY (),
                @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE ();

            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        END CATCH
    END
END
```

Calling it from within SSMS works fine, that is `exec usp_backup_database 'dbname'` successfully backs up dbname every time!

However, I have a C# program that I call this stored procedure from and it never does anything. No exceptions at all, just nothing happens.

I started out calling this from Entity Framework 6 and that threw a very unhelpful exception which is why I moved to calling the stored procedure from .NET instead of EF (and this explains the funky `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` construct in my code which pulls out just the SQL connection string portion of the larger EF connection string).

The user I am connecting with to SQL Server via .NET is a member of the sysadmin role so I don't think it's a permission issue. Any thoughts from anyone?

```
private static void BackupDatabase(string dbName)
{
        try
        {
            var efcb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(Core.WPMMasterConnectionString);

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(efcb.ProviderConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_backup_database", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DBName", dbName));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            DisplayUtils.ShowLine(sqlex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayUtils.ShowLine(ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a stored procedure within C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-within-c-sharp-program) You need to add `{ CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }`

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception? if the CommandType is wrong it will throw an error

Comment: Unless it's a very small database I'd expect an SqlException when the backup takes more than 30 seconds to complete and a timeout gets raised. You may wish to set a [cmd.CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout) value.

Comment: You should also try using the `SqlParameter (string parameterName, System.Data.SqlDbType dbType, int size)` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor) in case it's defaulting to `nvarchar(1)` and truncating your dbName.

Comment: It was the missing commandtype.storedprocedure, thanks for the help!